How to enable the bootstrap HTML5 menu to dropdown
We have a menu in one of our sites that we inherited from the previous project. That menu used to work, but now it doesn't. It uses bootstrap libraries version 3
The menu doesn't dropdown, stays frozen, any idea how it can be fixed?
Here is the HTML code
         <div class="" id="navbar1">
             <ul>
                 <li class="dropdown Some_header" style="width:190px; " ><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle header_dd_link" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="../images/usFlag.svg" class="TradeIconUS" />Some title<small><span class="caret"></span></small></a>                         
                     <ul class="dropdown-menu dd_1" style="width:850px; ">
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-3">
                                 <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                     <li><a href="https://www.somemainsite.com">Some main site</a></li>
                                     <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site1.com">some site 1</a></li>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site2.com">some site 2</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                                 <br />                                 
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-3">
                                 <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                     <li><a href="https://www.trade.gov/research">Another main site</a></li>
                                     <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site3.com">some site 3</a></li>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site4.com">some site 4</a></li>
                                 </ul>
                                 <br />
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <!-- row -->
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-3">
                                 <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                     <li><a href="https://www.trade.gov/attend-event">Some main site</a></li>
                                     <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site3.com">some site 5</a></li>
                                     <li class="col-1"><a href="https://www.site4.com">some site 6</a></li>                                     </ul>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </ul>                             
                 </li>
             </ul>
         </div>


Your HTML is invalid. A <div> cannot be the child of <ul>

Here is a revised version of your HTML code. Hope this helps.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap 3 Dropdown Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="navbar1" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown Some_header" style="width:190px;">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle header_dd_link" style="padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px;" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg" class="TradeIconUS" width="20" /> 
        Some title
        <small><span class="caret"></span></small>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dd_1" style="width:850px;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li><a href="https://www.somemainsite.com">Some main site</a></li>
              <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
              <li><a href="https://www.site1.com">some site 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.site2.com">some site 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li><a href="https://www.trade.gov/research">Another main site</a></li>
              <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
              <li><a href="https://www.site3.com">some site 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.site4.com">some site 4</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-3">
            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
              <li><a href="https://www.trade.gov/attend-event">Some main site</a></li>
              <div class="header_dropdown_bar"></div>
              <li><a href="https://www.site5.com">some site 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="https://www.site6.com">some site 6</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>




Your revised HTML still contains the same invalid markup he has.
